# Roots of $2^{\frac x2} + (\sqrt{2} +1)^x = (5+2 \sqrt{2})^{\frac x2} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried differentiating the equation to get minima and maxima, but failed to find the roots even there. Trial and error provides the answer=2, however, I'm searching for a proper method. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewrite as
$$a^{x/2}+b^{x/2}=1,$$
with $$a=\frac{2}{5+2\sqrt2}\text{ and }b=\frac{\left(\sqrt2+1\right)^2}{5+2\sqrt2}=\frac{3+2\sqrt2}{5+2\sqrt2}.$$

As $0<a,b<1$, the sum of exponentials is strictly decreasing and there is at most one root.

The solution $x=2$ is quasi-obvious, as $a+b=1$.

Comment: The part with the derivative is not needed. To establish the variation of $a^x+b^x$ as a function of $x$, simply note that $0\lt a,b\lt1$.

Comment: Thanks Yves for the answer, but, can you please elaborate the derivative part? :)

Comment: @Did: indeed. I am simplifying my answer.

Comment: "Exactly one root" should not be too difficult to deduce now... :-)

Comment: Thanks Yves for the feedback.

Comment: @Did: interestingly, the equation can be rewritten as $X^\alpha+X=1$, with $\alpha=\ln a/\ln b$, an irrational number, and it has an algebraic solution.